# iPhone 4S Home Button Flush

Tags: iphone

I've noticed over the last couple of weeks (to month) that the home button on my black 4S is becoming depressed relative to the case - only a very small amount but it now lacks the feedback it had when new.

Having looked at my housemate's 4S of the same age and probably slightly worse care, his is still perfectly flush. Is this normal / is the button on mine defective? I'm aware that I am probably being over-careful, but on my old i4 the home button gave up entirely after 14 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way to get a quick read would be to take it into any of the retail stores. You could check with 4 or 5 floor models and something like that is pretty easy to feel by setting a few phones down on the table and getting two or three people to compare them.

It's likely something small is stuck inside the switch area (like a grain of sand or smaller) or the spring got physically depressed more than it should.

You might get it swapped if the feel of the button is different or at least get it seen at the bar and have the genius write it up so there is a history of it not feeling perfect on the service record. (just in case you want to call in for a repair later over the phone)

Comment: It's lower than the ones in the Apple store, I checked that. I'll give it to a genius and see what they come up with :) Thank you!

Comment: Awesome - when a physical issue is obvious, they usually get sorted in minutes. Do turn on iCloud backup or be sure you have a good backup before seeing the genius. iPhone 3/3GS can get new screens, but the 4/4S end up as a whole unit swap.